# Maximize constrained log-sum

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Given constants $c>0$ and $\beta_i \in [0, \infty)^d$, for $i=1,..,n$, I want to (numerically?) solve the following problem:

$\max_{x \in [0, \infty)^d} \sum_{i=1}^n \log(\beta_i^T x), \text{ subject to } ||x||_1=c.$

My attempt:

1 - By definition of the problem, $x \in [0, \infty)^d$, so the constraint is equivalent to $\sum_{j=1}^d x_j = c$.

2 - $\log(\cdot)$ is strictly concave, $\beta_i^T x$ are linear functions, and the constraint is also linear, so the objective is concave. Thus, any local maximum is a global maximum.

3 - Our constrained objective yields the following Lagrangian:

$L(x, \lambda, \mu) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log(\beta_i^T x) + \lambda(c-\sum_{j=1}^d x_j) + \sum_{j=1}^d\mu_jx_j$

4 - From KKT conditions, the optimal solution $x^*$ and suitable parameters $\lambda^*$ and $\mu^*$ satisfy:

$\nabla_x L(x^*, \lambda^*, \mu^*) = 0, \,\,\, \lambda^*(c-\sum_{j=1}^d x_j^*)=0, \,\,\, \mu_j^*x_j^*=0, \text{ and } \mu_j^* \geq 0, \text{ for } j=1,...,d.$

However, except for some simple particular cases (e.g., $n=d=2$), I am not being able to solve this problem analytically... Questions:

Q1 - Is it possible to solve the problem analytically in the general case? (I suppose it is not.)

Q2 - Assuming the answer to Q1 is 'No', what would be a suitable numerical optimization algorithm to solve it?

Comment: Do you know that $n = d$, or $n > d$, or are you only interested in the general case?

Comment: I was thinking about the general case... Anyway, the case where $n \geq d$ is more important for me, so you may assume this condition holds if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KKT conditions (which necessarily hold at an optimal solution since the feasible region is polyhedral) that you've written out yield $\lambda^* - \mu^*_j = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{\beta_{ij}}{\beta^{T}_i x^*}, \:\: \forall j \in \{1,\cdots,d\}$. Multiplying each of these equations by $x^*_j$, using complementary slackness conditions, and summing up yields $\sum_{j=1}^{d} \lambda^* x^*_j = 1$, which along with the equality constraint implies $\lambda^* = \frac{1}{c}$.

The conditions we are left with are: 
\begin{align*}
&\mu^*_j + \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{\beta_{ij}}{\beta^{T}_i x^*} = \frac{1}{c}, \:\: \forall j \in \{1,\cdots,d\}, \\
&\sum_{j} x^*_j = c, \:\: x^* \geq 0, \\
&\mu^*_j x_j = 0, \:\: \forall j \in \{1,\cdots,d\}, \:\: \text{and}\\
&\mu^*_j \geq 0, \:\: \forall j \in \{1,\cdots,d\}.
\end{align*}

It doesn't seem to me like there's a closed form solution to this system in general.

A numerical option for solving your problem directly (without going through KKT conditions) is mirror descent, see Example 4.2 [here](http://stanford.edu/~jduchi/PCMIConvex/Duchi16.pdf). This should be particularly effective for your problem.

Comment: "First, note that the constraints $x_j=0$ will not be active at a solution." Counter-example: suppose $n=1$, $d=2$, $c=1$ and $\beta_1=(2,1)$. Then, $x^* = (1, 0)$, am I wrong?

Comment: @D... you are correct, my mistake. Will delete soon and try again later

Comment: Anyway, I don't get why this step is important for your solution. I haven't gone through all its details yet, but it seems correct. Is it necessary for the KKT conditions to hold? Why?

Comment: @D... see the updated answer

Comment: Great, thank you for your effort and for the reference you're sharing with me! :) I'll mark it as solved as soon as I go through all the steps you derived.